# Slight abuse of notation in the definition of atlas?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Im reading the book *Analysis II* of Amann and Escher. It said in page 252 or so, as in the article of wikipedia, that if $\{\varphi_\alpha:\alpha\in\mathrm A\}$ is an atlas of an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$, namely $M$, and if $U_\alpha$ is the domain of the chart $\varphi_\alpha$ then $\color{red}{M=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathrm A}U_\alpha}$.

At the same time its said that $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)=:V_\alpha\in\Bbb R^m$ must be open, and also that $\varphi_\alpha$ is an homeomorphism. This would imply that $U_\alpha$ are open sets in $\Bbb R^n$.

After its said that if $M$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$ then, according to the above, $M$ have a finite atlas. But then I dont see how is possible that the equality in red can be true, because arbitrary union of open sets is open.

This is a kind of abuse of notation or Im overlooking something? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If the open sets cover $M$, then their union is closed as well as open (if $X$ is any topological space then $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself are both closed and open). For a  concrete example with $m = 1$, $n = 2$, think of  the unit circle $S^1$ in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$ covered by the two open arcs you get by puncturing it at two different points. Note that these arcs are **not** open in $\Bbb{R}^2$ but they are open in $S^1$ and are homeomorphic to open intervals in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: but the $U_\alpha$ are open in $\Bbb R^n$ and $M$ is a compact set in $\Bbb R^n$. The unique clopen sets in $\Bbb R^n$ is $\Bbb R^n$ itself and the empty set. Im working in the standard topology.

Comment: The $U_\alpha$ are open in $M$, not in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do you see now that you can't infer that the $U_{\alpha}$ are open in $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: ok, ok... I see now. Thank you very much.